# Stochastic optimal control problems in Python

Tags: python, gekko

Does anyone know of a python package that solves stochastic optimal control problems?

I have found Gekko that solves control problems, but I could not find a way to use it for stochastic problems.

Comment: If there are no answers to this question, try https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/. But, I must confess: I don't know if stochastic optimal control problems have any relation to computational science.

Comment: David, stochastic optimal control is also called dynamic programming and it fundamentally has to do with computer science but the vast majority of "computer scientists" have no idea about it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is a minimal example of [stochastic model predictive control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_control#Stochastic_model_predictive_control) with Gekko where the parameter K is randomly chosen. The 10 instances of the model are collectively optimized to minimize the squared error from 40 (target).

[image: Stochastic Model Predictive Control]

```py
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# uncertain parameter
n = 10
K = np.random.rand(n)+1.0

m = GEKKO()
m.time = np.linspace(0,20,41)

# manipulated variable
p = m.MV(value=0, lb=0, ub=100)
p.STATUS = 1 
p.DCOST = 0.1  
p.DMAX = 20

# controlled variable
v = m.Array(m.CV,n)
for i in range(n):
    v[i].STATUS = 1
    v[i].SP = 40
    v[i].TAU = 5
    m.Equation(10*v[i].dt() == -v[i] + K[i]*p)

# solve optimal control problem
m.options.IMODE = 6
m.options.CV_TYPE = 2
m.solve()

# plot results
plt.figure()
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(m.time,p.value,'b-',LineWidth=2)
plt.ylabel('MV')
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot([0,m.time[-1]],[40,40],'k-',LineWidth=3)
for i in range(n):
    plt.plot(m.time,v[i].value,':',LineWidth=2)
plt.ylabel('CV')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.show()
```

The [Gekko paper (see Section 4)](https://www.mdpi.com/2227-9717/6/8/106/htm) gives an overview of other optimal control packages as well. Some of them may have stochastic optimization capabilities. I also found the [StoDynProg](https://github.com/pierre-haessig/stodynprog) Python package for solving stochastic optimal control problems but it hasn't been updated for a while and I don't have experience with it. Victor Zavala shared work on [stochastic optimal control of gas networks](https://youtu.be/JYni77V1Nt8) and Fengqi You shared work on [optimization under uncertainty](https://youtu.be/7eQpuBVeCiQ) that may also provide inspiration and toolsets that they use.

Comment: I added this and another stochastic optimal control problem with uncertain time delay here: https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/StochasticOptimalControl